# Could not read config file magento2

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to create a simple theme in magento2 on my localhost,
I added all directories and logo image following this link [enter link description here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

but when I refresh the frontend page it gave me this message

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Could
>   not read config file

Comment: It looks like permission issue

Comment: Share your code with location of files

Comment: remove `var/generation` and `var/cache` and then  run `setup:di:compile` and `setup:cache:clean` command